# Specifying dependencies with gulp-jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, gulp, gulp-jasmine

I have the following `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('spec/test.js')
        .pipe(jasmine());
});
```

The code inside `spec/test.js` uses a global `angular` variable, however, and throws an error about it being undefined when I run gulp task `default`. Let's say `angular` is defined in file `spec/lib.js`, in global scope.

How do I tell `jasmine()` what dependencies it needs to load first into the global scope before running the `describe()`s inside `test.js`? In other words, how do I tell `jasmine()` to load `spec/lib.js` first, before it runs the tests?

Comment: Add it to the `src` call perhaps? `gulp.src(['spec/lib.js', 'spec/test.js'])`. You could also use *wiredep* if you're using bower dependencies

Comment: I'm fighting the same battle, I tried to pass a config object to jasmine pipe function like `jasmine({config: {files: ["foo.js", "bar,js"]}})` but It still not working in my case

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **KARMA**?

[KARMA LINK](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html)

If you use karma, jasmine, and gulp, which I do, you can configure your testing like this

> In **gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma').server; // Note the server property here.

gulp.task('karma', function (done) {
  karma.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
  }, done);
});
```

> You will need to import ng-html2js for angular templates

```
npm install ng-html2js
```

> In **karma.config.js** (You must create)

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  config.set({

  // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
  basePath: '',

  frameworks: ['jasmine'],

  files: setFilesUpForTesting(),

  // list of files to exclude during testing. CHANGE THIS TO YOURS!!!
  exclude: [
    'public/js/boot.js',
    'public/js/socket.io.js'
    // 'yourRootPath/folder/stuff.js
  ],

  // NOTE THE NG-HTML2JS preprocessor you will need via NPM.    
  preprocessors: {
    // CHANGE TO YOUR PATH for all HTML PARTIALS.
    'public/directives/**/partials/*.html': 'ng-html2js',
    'public/directives/**/*.js': ['coverage']
  },

  ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    stripPrefix:'public',
    moduleName: 'templates'
  },

  reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

  coverageReporter: {
    type : 'html',
    dir : 'coverage/'
  },

  port: 9876,

  colors: true,

  // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


  // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
  autoWatch: true,

  // start these browsers
  // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
  browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------ >
// Below code is for running either single or all test files.
// To run a single test, just pass in the test file name like so...

// If the test file name was rs-test-me-now_spec.js
// To spool up Karma you would enter

// gulp karma --single-test=rs-test-me-now  <note the proceeding double hyphen>
// To just run all tests
// gulp karma

// CHANGE THE FILE PATHS BELOW!!!!!

var fixedPath = [
  'public/js/jquery.js',
  'public/js/jquery-ui.min.js',
  'public/js/foundation.min.js',
  'public/js/angular.min.js',
  'public/js/angular-mocks.js',

];

var baseTestPath = 'public/test/'; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR ROOT PATH!!!

function setFilesUpForTesting(){
  fixedPath.push( testPath());
  return fixedPath;
}

function testPath(){
  return singleTestPath() || fullTestPath();
}

function fullTestPath(){
  return  'public/test/**/*_spec.js'; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SPEC FOLDER!!!
  // like rootFolder/somethinghere/spec/**/*_spec.js
  // note the underscore that proceeds the spec.js. Get rid of if you file name does not have it.
}

function singleTestPath(){
  var passedArgument = process.argv.filter(function(item){ if(/--single-test=/.test(item)){return item; }});
  if( isEmpty( passedArgument )){ return false; }
  return baseTestPath + '**/*' + fileName( passedArgument ) + '_spec.js';
}

function fileName( argument ){
  if( !argument ){ return; }
  return argument[0].replace('--single-test=', '');
}

function isEmpty( array ){
  return array.length === 0;
}

------------------- END KARMA.CONFIG.js file ----------------------
```

> **Now to run tests**

```
// To run all tests
gulp karma

// To run one single file test
gulp karma --single-test=rs-test-me-now
```

**NOTE:** If you can't get it to work right off let me know and we'll TS it. Perhaps I missed something. My test files are named something_test.js, not something_spec.js. I changed the code to create _spec.js. Also, you have to make sure you have included all the files you need to run Angular. I provided some examples in my karma.config.js. I run Angular as well.

The preprocessor (ng-html2js) compiles the angular templates for directives. You must install it in your package.json.